# How to bring 'Compile' command back to life?

Tags: winedt

I'm trying to compile my file,but strangely the 'compile' order doesn't work[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgVlK.png)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are you under WinEdt? What you highlighted is not the ‘Compile’ button..

Comment: This can happen if a non-tex file is the master file or if the tex file has not the tex mode. Check the status line for the mode or go to projects and use "set main file".

Comment: It's under WinEdt 7.0, and I tried 'F9',it didn't work.

Comment: Could you check the document Mode in the `Status line`? It should be `TeX`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you,I've reinstalled it.Maybe it's not WinEdt's problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're absolutely right!